# Why is transform.data.table so much slower than transform.data.frame?

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I have a small data.table and using `transform` with it takes forever. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
#data.table 1.8.8
set.seed(1) 

dataraw <- data.table(sig1 = runif(80000, 0, 9999),
                      sig2 = runif(80000, 0, 9999),
                      sig3 = runif(80000, 0, 9999))

system.time(transform(dataraw, d = 1))
#  user      system     elapsed 
#16.345       0.016      16.359 

dataraw2 <- as.data.frame(dataraw)

system.time(transform(dataraw2, d = 1))
# user      system     elapsed 
#0.002       0.002       0.005
```

Why is `transform` so slow with a data.table in comparison to when used with a data.frame?

Comment: This has been [fixed long before](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2599&group_id=240&atid=975) (in v1.8.10!!). Could you please accept an answer and close this question? Thanks.

Comment: sure. although I'd rephrase it as : "bad implementation. use the fixed version"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Update: This has been fixed long back, in v1.8.10. From NEWS:

> o  The slowness of `transform()` on `data.table` has been fixed, `#2599`. But, please use `:=`.

---

Although it's clear from the documentation and from `?transform.data.table` (from SenorO's post as well) that the idiomatic way is to use `:=` (assign by reference), which is incredibly fast, I think it's still interesting to know ***why*** `transform` is slower on `data.table`. From what I've managed to comprehend so far, `transform.data.table` is *not always slower*.

I'll make an attempt to answer that here. It doesn't seem to be a problem with `transform.data.table` per-se, rather in its call to `data.table()` function. By looking at `data.table:::transform.data.table`, the lag comes from the line:

```
ans <- do.call("data.table", c(list(`_data`), e[!matched]))
```

So, let's benchmark this line with a big `data.table` with values in order:

```
DT <- data.table(x=1:1e5, y=1:1e5, z=1:1e5)
system.time(do.call("data.table", c(list(DT), list(d=1))))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.003   0.003   0.026
```

Oh this is extremely fast! Let's benchmark the same, but with values *not* in order:

```
DT <- data.table(x=sample(1e5), y=sample(1e5), z=sample(1e5))
system.time(do.call("data.table", c(list(DT), list(d=1))))

   user  system elapsed 
  7.986   0.016   8.099 

# tested on 1.8.8 and 1.8.9
```

It gets slow. What's causing this difference? To do that we'll have to debug `data.table()` function. By doing

```
DT <- data.table(x=as.numeric(1:1e5), y=as.numeric(1:1e5), z=as.numeric(1:1e5))
debugonce(data.table)
transform(DT, d=1)
```

and by hitting *"enter"* successively, you'll be able to find the reason for the such slowness is at the line:

```
exptxt = as.character(tt) # roughly about 7.2 seconds
```

It's clear that `as.character` becomes the issue. Why? To do this, compare:

```
as.character(data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10))
# [1] "1:10" "1:10"

as.character(data.frame(x=sample(10), y=sample(10)))
# [1] "c(9, 10, 4, 7, 6, 5, 1, 3, 8, 2)" "c(8, 5, 3, 7, 6, 10, 9, 1, 4, 2)"
```

Repeat this on bigger data to see that `as.character` on sampled `data.frame` gets *slower*.

Now then, the question becomes, why isn't

```
data.table(x = sample(1e5), y=sample(1e5))
```

time consuming? This is because, the input given to `data.table()` function is *substituted* (with `subsitute()`). In this case, `tt` becomes:

```
$x
sample(1e+05)

$y
sample(1e+05)
```

and `as.character(tt)` then just becomes:

```
# [1] "sample(1e+05)" "sample(1e+05)"
```

This means, if you were to do:

```
DT <- data.table(x = c(1,3,4,1,4,1,3,1,2...), y = c(1,1,4,1,3,4,1,1,3...))
```

I'd suppose that this'll take a LOT of time (which one doesn't usually do and hence no issues).

Comment: +1 for finding the source of the issue. I do think this is a valid question even if it turned into a weird fight over the philosophy behind R.

Comment: @SeñorO i dont want to restart this but that had nothing to do with R. it is a general principle that the only good reason for loosing speed in one usage scenario is to gain some in other usage. as the generic transform does not convey information about a particular traversal, there are no good reason, for any langage, to degrade performance. that is just really common sense. if people try to tell you otherwise, they are fraudsters.

Comment: @nicolas, for what it's worth, [*it is a known issue; FR#2599*](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=240&atid=975&func=detail&aid=2599). It just wasn't a priority because `transform` is not really to be used with `data.table` (or rather doesn't make sense to be used with). Ultimately, it'll get fixed. I suggest you read the docs and FAQ to best utilise `data.table`. If you think there's a design flaw/any other flaw, you should take it to the developers - [*register on `data.table` mailing list*](https://r-forge.r-project.org/mail/?group_id=240).

Comment: I would argue that is a sensible thing : it keeps a function's code independent of the argument's implementation, in the absence of a need to specialize. hence my original surprise where I thought I missed something, which I did : the comment in the documentation + the bug report.

Answer (score 11):

From `?transform.data.table`:

```
transform by group is particularly slow. Please use := by group instead.

within, transform and other similar functions in data.table are not just provided 
for users who expect them to work, but for non-data.table-aware packages to 
retain keys, for example. Hopefully the (much) faster and more convenient 
data.table syntax will be used in time.
```

As @Roland suggests, you should always break down components of your code to find out what is actually taking up time/resources. In this case it is not `log`, but `transform`. Use `:=` for data.tables, `transform` for data.frames, lists, etc.

The culprit is not `log`:

```
> dt <- data.table(A=1:1000000)
> system.time(transform(as.data.frame(dt), B=A * 1))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.00    0.02    0.01 
> system.time(transform(dt, B=A * 1))
   user  system elapsed 
  14.61    0.00   14.61
```